# Ice Chat Application

Tags: c#, java, ice

I'm ICE starter. At http://zeroc.com there is good tutorial on how to create chat. I decided to use the tutorial as base. And first thing I tried to do was writing ChatRoom class in c# instead of given c++ implementation. I tried to do the same in my c# code. ChatRoom implementation in c++:

```
// C++
class ChatRoomCallbackAdapter { /* ... */ };
typedef IceUtil::Handle<ChatRoomCallbackAdapter> ChatRoomCallbackAdapterPtr;
class ChatRoom : public IceUtil::Shared
{
public:
    ChatRoom(bool trace, const Ice::LoggerPtr& logger);
    void reserve(const std::string&);
    void unreserve(const std::string&);
    void join(const std::string&, const ChatRoomCallbackAdapterPtr&);
    void leave(const std::string&);
    Ice::Long send(const std::string&, const std::string&);
private:
    typedef std::map<std::string, ChatRoomCallbackAdapterPtr> ChatRoomCallbackMap;
    ChatRoomCallbackMap _members;
    std::set<std::string> _reserved;
    IceUtil::Mutex _mutex;
    const bool _trace;
    const Ice::LoggerPtr _logger;
};
```

Some piece of class-members implementation:

```
// ...
void ChatRoom::reserve(const string& name)
{
    IceUtil::Mutex::Lock sync(_mutex);
    if(_reserved.find(name) != _reserved.end() ||
       _members.find(name) != _members.end())
    {
        throw string("The name " + name + " is already in use.");
    }
    _reserved.insert(name);
}
// ...
```

I was writng next:

```
public class ChatRoom : IceUtil
```

when I encountered an error. I found that IceUtil dll in distribution package isn't COM-visible therefore I can't use it in my c# project.

What can I use instead of c++

```
IceUtil::Handle<T>
```

as far as I understand it is a smart pointer.
How can I implement server like the one's given in c#?

Would it be the same in c# (talking about mutexes) comparing to above c++ class:

```
public class ChatRoom
{
    // ...
    void Reserve(System.String Name)
    {
        lock(this)
        {
            // operations
        }
    }               
}
```

?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not support reference counted pointers out of the box, that is why C++ API has [`IceUtil::Handle<>`](http://www.zeroc.com/doc/Ice-3.3.1/manual/IceUtil.52.7.html) template. C# obviously does not need it. I'd recommend you start learning Ice for C# using C# examples rather than C++. You can find a lot of C# client/server examples in `democs` folder of [demos packages](http://www.zeroc.com/download/Ice/3.4/Ice-3.4.1-demos.tar.gz). And, of course, Ice has absolutely nothing to do with `COM` technology, except that it is kind of a replacement.

Comment: Please look at re-edit. Am I right about locking? And what does the inhertance from IceUtil::Shared give to ChatRoomClass. I have no clue what is it in IceUtil::Shared...

Comment: `IceUtil::Shared` is a base class which Ice objects in C++ have to inherit. It provides an interface to increase and decrease reference counter, and some other methods. You don't need it in C#. As for the locking - yes, you have to synchronize access to shared resources and Ice methods can be invoked from different threads in parallel. The only thing that seems to be missing is inheritance from `CharRoomDisp_` abstract class. That class should be generated from Ice file. Once again, read trough C# examples first.

Comment: Yes I know about servants and server objects... this thing I've read tonite. Thanks! I'm gonna fight this))

Answer (score 4):

I don't know anything about ICE, but their website lists a [.NET implementation](http://zeroc.com/icedotnet.html) - why don't you use that instead of COM if you want to use C#? There's even a [section of documentation with an example of a C# server](http://www.zeroc.com/doc/Ice-3.2b/manual/Hello.4.5.html).

Comment: Implementation of the Ice API.

Comment: Yes I know but it is surfacing and has no direct connection to the Chat Demo application architecture. In the last it seems to be more complex.